# Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema en cuestion de mostrar los datos del usuario que esta usando su cuenta tipo perfil

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para el perfil mas que manda a llamar todos los usuarios en vez de llamar al usuario que esta activo en el sitio, lo que trato de hacer es mandar a llamara los datos del usuario que esta usando o que ingreso a mi interfaz sin tener que mandar a llamar los demás usuarios

```
<thead>
        <?php
        session_start();
        include("connection.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        ?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
        <div class="perfil-usuario-body">
            <div class="perfil-usuario-bio">
                <h3 class="titulo"><?php echo $mostrar['usuario'] ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="perfil-usuario-footer">
                <ul class="lista-datos">
                <li><i class="icono fas fa-map-signs"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['matricula'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fa fa-calendar"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['fn'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fas fa-briefcase"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['area'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fa fa-envelope"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['correo'] ?></td></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="lista-datos">
                    <a href="home.html">
                        <li><i class="icono fa fa-home"></i> Inicio</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <li><i class="icono fa fa-sign-out"></i> Cerrar Sesion</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: A tu select le falta un `where` que filtre a los usuarios y te deje únicamente el que quieres. Cómo es exactamente ese `where` no se puede decir con exactitud sin conocer la estructura de la tabla y de tu sesión. Lo usual es tener un campo `id` en la tabla y tener ese dato en la sesión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Carlos y bienvenido.

Para mostrar solo el perfil del usuario que ha iniciado sesión, debes filtrar la consulta SQL basada en el ID del usuario o algún otro campo único que identifique al usuario activo. Suponiendo que en tu sistema guardes el `ID` (o un identificador único) del usuario que ha iniciado sesión en una variable de sesión, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

1. Suponiendo que cuando el usuario inicia sesión, guardas su ID en `$_SESSION['user_id']`.
2. Modifica la consulta SQL para que solo seleccione al usuario que ha iniciado sesión:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
```

Aquí está el código modificado:

```php
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");
// Asegúrate de que hay un usuario logueado antes de continuar
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    die("Usuario no autenticado");
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($mostrar) { 
?>
    <div class="perfil-usuario-body">
        <div class="perfil-usuario-bio">
            <h3 class="titulo"><?php echo $mostrar['usuario'] ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="perfil-usuario-footer">
            <ul class="lista-datos">
                <li><i class="icono fas fa-map-signs"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['matricula'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fa fa-calendar"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['fn'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fas fa-briefcase"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['area'] ?></td></li>
                <li><i class="icono fa fa-envelope"></i><td><?php echo $mostrar['correo'] ?></td></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="lista-datos">
                <a href="home.html">
                    <li><i class="icono fa fa-home"></i> Inicio</li>
                </a>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li><i class="icono fa fa-sign-out"></i> Cerrar Sesion</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

**Importante**: Asegúrate de que tu sistema esté protegido contra ataques de SQL Injection. El código anterior no tiene medidas de protección y se presenta de esta manera solo por simplicidad. Utilizar consultas preparadas con `mysqli` o PDO es una manera de protegerse contra este tipo de ataques.

Comment: hola buenas tardes muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo mucho para solucionar varios errores mas que me aparece un error de error en la array de id, y agregue un $_SESSION["id"]; pero solo me da los datos del usuario con el id 1 y no los demás, ademas elimine el if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    die("Usuario no autenticado");
} para saber si existía un error en algún código que no lo pudiera ver ya que solo me marca usuario no autenticado